# React native use fetch inside for loop

Tags: json, google-maps, react-native, fetch

In my React native app, I have an array of objects, each object has 3 properties: address, latitude and longitude. Latitude and longitude are initially null, so I m using google api for reverse geocoding. Since it is an array, I m looping inside my array and fetch google url to get lat and lng from given address. But when I try to save latitude and longitude inside my object, I have an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating:
>   locations[i].latitude =
>   responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lat)

Here is my code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){

          if (locations[i].address){

            var googleRequestUrl = this.state.GoogleAPIUrl + locations[i].address;

            fetch(googleRequestUrl)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              locations[i].latitude = responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
              locations[i].longitude = responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.warn(error);
            })
            .done();
          }
        }
```

The google API I m using is: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="

I have already checked if I m getting the response with response.text(): it gives me a complete response, with lat and lng.

I cannot understand why it gives me that error, what am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with having fetch inside a loop? Or the problem is something else?

Any suggestions or better solutions are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of your addresses cannot be geocoded correctly and you are trying to access non-existing result on response object.

I would check whether result exist and continue accordingly.

```
const result = responseJson.results[0];
if (result) {
    locations[i].latitude = result.geometry.location.lat;
    locations[i].longitude = result.geometry.location.lng;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code:

```
.then((responseJson) => {
    locations[i].latitude = responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    locations[i].longitude = responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
})
```

isn't going to do what you want it to do.

Since this bit of code runs asynchronously, it will use the value of `i` that it finds at the time of execution.  And by time you get a response from the server, your `for` loop will already have completed execution.  And the value of `i` at the end of the for loop?  It will be 4.

So you will be trying to store the value (for every fetch) in `locations[4]` which is undefined.

To fix this issue, you could do a couple things:
1. The easiest, if you are using ES6 is to declare a constant in the for loop equal to the loop variable.  This basically creates a closure over the index to allow you to reference the correct value later.  It'll look something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    if (locations[i].address){
        var googleRequestUrl = this.state.GoogleAPIUrl + locations[i].address;

        const index = i;
        fetch(googleRequestUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            locations[index].latitude = responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            locations[index].longitude = responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error);
        })
        .done();
    }
}
```

2. pass the loop variable to another function that fetches the data and performs the change
3. use an array map function that basically does #2 but with anonymous functions

```

```
locations.map((location) => {
    if (location.address) {
        var googleRequestUrl = this.state.GoogleAPIUrl + location.address;
        fetch(googleRequestUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            location.latitude = responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            location.longitude = responseJson.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error);
        })
        .done();
    }
);
```